# Как узнать из какой строки и какого файла был вызван метод класса?

Tags: ооп, php

Как узнать из какой строки и какого файла был вызван метод класса?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вообще не хочется попу отрывать от стула, то

[debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-backtrace.php)

спасет мир. 
Предупреждаю: крайне тяжелая функция для повседневного использования в релизе.

UPD:

> есть альтернатива?

Конечно.

1. делаем логирование. Внутри вызова каждой функции, в самом начале константы **METHOD** и **FILE** отправляем в какой-нибудь глобальный массив, либо в свойство класса логирования. Потом можно извлечь и посмотреть что за чем было вызвано.
2. использовать продвинутую IDE. Про них уже на этом сайте исписано множество тем. Выбирайте любую.
3. если вы мазохист, можно вручную отследить весь путь развития программы.

Comment: "Если вообще не хочется попу отрывать от стула" есть альтернатива?

Comment: Добавил обновление альтернатив

Comment: debug_backtrace() покажет далеко не всё..

Comment: @Photon, очень многозначительный комментарий. Не изволите ли развернуть тему?

Comment: Во-первых, у debug_backtrace() есть ограничение на количество вложенных вызовов.  Т.е. (если мне не изменяет память), он останавливается на глубине 30.
Во-вторых, очень часто эта функция отрабатывает неверно, т.е. не показывает правильной картины.

Это достаточно развернутый комментарий?

Comment: Нет. Но уже лучше. Особенно хотелось бы узнать про некорректные отработки. Да и про ограничение размера стека вызова в официальной документации ни слова.

Answer (score 0):

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
$caller = $trace[1];
echo "Called by {$caller['function']}";
if (isset($caller['class'])) echo " in {$caller['class']}";
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Сам постоянно нарываюсь на этот ответ и всё время правлю под себя :-) Так что оставлю как шпаргалку, на будущее:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();

echo "<strong>Trace calls:</strong><br/>";

foreach ($trace as $key => $item) {
    // Информация о функции и классе
    $calledBy = isset($item['class']) ? "{$item['class']}::{$item['function']}" : $item['function'];

    // Информация о файле и строке
    $file = isset($item['file']) ? $item['file'] : 'unknown file';
    $line = isset($item['line']) ? $item['line'] : 'unknown line';

    // Вывод информации для каждого вызова
    echo "#{$key}: Called by {$calledBy} in {$file} on line {$line}<br/>";
}

echo "<hr/>";
```

Answer (score -2):

Согласен с **knes**`ом

```
echo bugs(print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));
// bugs - название вашей функции или метода
```

все покажет

Comment: Не очень понял ваш код, если честно. О_о
Вы в качестве параметра функции передаете ей строку, выданную дебагом в момент вызова функции?! А он успеет записать вызов? Или bugs - это функция обработки?