# Как узнать адрес вызывающего файла

Tags: php

Имеется следующая структура.
Из файла `main/views/index.php` вызываю (`include_once`) файл `bootstrap.php`, который подключает стили, функции и классы из папки `application/`.

Хочу, чтобы `bootstrap.php` также подключал файлы из папки `static`, расположенной там же, где лежит `index`, который его подключает. Но как получить путь вызывающего файла?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/142692/186083 похожий, но про функцию, а не файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вероятно, вам поможет

```
 $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]
```

> Абсолютный путь к исполняемому скрипту.

http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Если я пропишу это в bootstrap.php я узнаю его путь. Но мне нужно узнать путь фала который вызвал bootstrap.php, то есть в моем случаи main/views/index.php. Ну или я не так понял документацию)

Comment: @Максим вы не так поняли документацию. текущий скрипт (`bootstrap`)доступен в `__FILE__`, а в `_SERVER` находится имя запрошенного (`index`).